Creating an FMU by packaging a zip
i’m currently trying to implement a physical model as an FMU to import it into a simulation tool Simulink for example.
From what I understood, I created a C source file which instantiates and imlements the FMU by using FMI functions (fmi3InstantiateCoSimulation, fmi3DoStep…), linked it with the FMI libraries and added a modelDescription XML file to describe the model’s behavior.
Now, to generate the FMU, do we need to use an FMU generation tool (OpenModelica…) or is it possible to generate an FMU from my position?
Thanks by advance !

It is both possible to create you FMU from an exporting tool (see https://fmi-standard.org/tools/ for a list, filtder for Export ME=Model Exchange or CS=Co-simulation) or create an FMU e.g. from C-Sources.
This depends very much, in which form you have model.
Generally the first way is much recommended, as you do not have to take care of so many details (such as creating a correct modelDescription.xml file)
For the second way (implementing the model equations by hand) you can take the examples from the Reference FMUs (https://github.com/modelica/reference-fmus) as a inspiration or blueprint.

Thank you for your answer. To contextualize, we start from an xml and source files so we thought it could be easier to generate the FMU from similar files. I have already coded the modelDescription.xml files as in the examples you provided and also a c file which instantiates the simulation from FMI libraries. But I don’t get how to go from those files (.zip) to an FMU? Is it directly an fmi function that is in charged of generating a .fmu ? Or should we code something? I tried to look into the reference fmus but didn’t see or missed the information.

An FMU is  a ZIP file; you can create the ZIP file with ending ".fmu" (see https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L267) or  simply rename it to ".fmu" if your ZIP file fulfills the FMI Standard (https://fmi-standard.org/)
(What do you mean with "FMI libraries"? The header files?)
You should then validate your FMU with the tools listed on https://fmi-standard.org/validation/
Other lightweight examples for FMUs created from C-Code can be found e.g. here: https://github.com/OpenSimulationInterface/osi-sensor-model-packaging/tree/master/examples

FMU4CPP is a CMake template project where you only need to implement functions from a base class using C++, and the ZIP and XML is generated for you. Perhaps it will help you get going.
https://github.com/Ecos-platform/fmu4cpp

You can also check the other sources at https://github.com/traversaro/awesome-fmi or https://github.com/fmi-tools.
